# Error "SIP/2.0 488 Not acceptable here"

Tags: asterisk, sip

I setup User "100" and " 200 ," I 'm trying to use the project sipml5 .

The server records the two users , the User "100" on this online Linphone .

The User "200 " records in sipml5 , but to make the call it shows this error:

```
`Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk9t8l09v01c | acquiring local media`

`Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk9t8l09v01c | acquired local media streams`

`Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk9t8l09v01c | ICE candidate received: candidate:3879386089 1 udp 2122260223 172.16.1.209 60702 typ host generation 0`

`Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk9t8l09v01c | ICE candidate received: candidate:3879386089 2 udp 2122260222 172.16.1.209 45410 typ host generation 0`

`Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk9t8l09v01c | ICE candidate received: candidate:2847491865 1 tcp 1518280447 172.16.1.209 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0`

`Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk9t8l09v01c | ICE candidate received: candidate:2847491865 2 tcp 1518280446 172.16.1.209 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0`

`Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk9t8l09v01c | ICE candidate received: candidate:288014909 2 udp 1686052606 189.35.140.74 62060 typ srflx raddr 172.16.1.209 rport 45410 generation 0`

`Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk9t8l09v01c | ICE candidate received: candidate:288014909 1 udp 1686052607 189.35.140.74 56282 typ srflx raddr 172.16.1.209 rport 60702 generation 0`

`Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:`

`INVITE sip:100@172.16.1.203 SIP/2.0<br>
Via: SIP/2.0/WS cam6bslroe6a.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK7117302
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:100@172.16.1.203>
From: "200" <sip:200@172.16.1.203>;tag=ur4c0oov9u
Call-ID: 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk
CSeq: 7760 INVITE
Contact: <sip:040c805k@cam6bslroe6a.invalid;transport=ws;ob>
Allow: ACK,CANCEL,BYE,OPTIONS,INFO,NOTIFY,INVITE
Content-Type: application/sdp
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.2
Content-Length: 1777
`

`v=0
o=- 6908994037829104915 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio
a=msid-semantic: WMS Mdtr3XiGc3ZYftGDwxeYDfspP9DqQwSRd17N
m=audio 56282 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 126
c=IN IP4 189.35.140.74
a=rtcp:62060 IN IP4 189.35.140.74
a=candidate:3879386089 1 udp 2122260223 172.16.1.209 60702 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:3879386089 2 udp 2122260222 172.16.1.209 45410 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:2847491865 1 tcp 1518280447 172.16.1.209 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:2847491865 2 tcp 1518280446 172.16.1.209 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:288014909 2 udp 1686052606 189.35.140.74 62060 typ srflx raddr 172.16.1.209 rport 45410 generation 0
a=candidate:288014909 1 udp 1686052607 189.35.140.74 56282 typ srflx raddr 172.16.1.209 rport 60702 generation 0
a=ice-ufrag:FK6gzTOP0l95UM39
a=ice-pwd:1ehRZElxNwmCq6mQpetD78w+
a=fingerprint:sha-256 2C:93:D5:54:53:96:34:18:DA:A6:3C:1A:59:5A:32:6B:3E:70:79:78:85:AC:AA:26:8F:D6:0B:5E:9C:DB:4A:8C
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=maxptime:60
a=ssrc:2011742822 cname:/+L6wPj8ErBqYw3L
a=ssrc:2011742822 msid:Mdtr3XiGc3ZYftGDwxeYDfspP9DqQwSRd17N dce80b6d-4fed-4409-af6c-275e470a0d73
a=ssrc:2011742822 mslabel:Mdtr3XiGc3ZYftGDwxeYDfspP9DqQwSRd17N
a=ssrc:2011742822 label:dce80b6d-4fed-4409-af6c-275e470a0d73`


`Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:`

`SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/WS cam6bslroe6a.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK7117302;received=172.16.1.209
From: "200" <sip:200@172.16.1.203>;tag=ur4c0oov9u
To: <sip:100@172.16.1.203>;tag=as5f539d65
Call-ID: 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk
CSeq: 7760 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 13.6.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="asterisk", nonce="26be674c"
Content-Length: 0`



`Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:`

`ACK sip:100@172.16.1.203 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WS cam6bslroe6a.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK7117302
To: <sip:100@172.16.1.203>;tag=as5f539d65
From: "200" <sip:200@172.16.1.203>;tag=ur4c0oov9u
Call-ID: 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk
Content-Length: 0
CSeq: 7760 ACK`



`Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:`

`INVITE sip:100@172.16.1.203 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WS cam6bslroe6a.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK4757152
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:100@172.16.1.203>
From: "200" <sip:200@172.16.1.203>;tag=ur4c0oov9u
Call-ID: 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk
CSeq: 7761 INVITE
Authorization: Digest algorithm=MD5, username="200", realm="asterisk", nonce="26be674c", uri="sip:100@172.16.1.203", response="7c400e75f1605a4893b99438a18b9560"
Contact: <sip:040c805k@cam6bslroe6a.invalid;transport=ws;ob>
Allow: ACK,CANCEL,BYE,OPTIONS,INFO,NOTIFY,INVITE
Content-Type: application/sdp
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: SIP.js/0.7.2
Content-Length: 1777`

`v=0
o=- 6908994037829104915 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio
a=msid-semantic: WMS Mdtr3XiGc3ZYftGDwxeYDfspP9DqQwSRd17N
m=audio 56282 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 126
c=IN IP4 189.35.140.74
a=rtcp:62060 IN IP4 189.35.140.74
a=candidate:3879386089 1 udp 2122260223 172.16.1.209 60702 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:3879386089 2 udp 2122260222 172.16.1.209 45410 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:2847491865 1 tcp 1518280447 172.16.1.209 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:2847491865 2 tcp 1518280446 172.16.1.209 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0
a=candidate:288014909 2 udp 1686052606 189.35.140.74 62060 typ srflx raddr 172.16.1.209 rport 45410 generation 0
a=candidate:288014909 1 udp 1686052607 189.35.140.74 56282 typ srflx raddr 172.16.1.209 rport 60702 generation 0
a=ice-ufrag:FK6gzTOP0l95UM39
a=ice-pwd:1ehRZElxNwmCq6mQpetD78w+
a=fingerprint:sha-256 2C:93:D5:54:53:96:34:18:DA:A6:3C:1A:59:5A:32:6B:3E:70:79:78:85:AC:AA:26:8F:D6:0B:5E:9C:DB:4A:8C
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=maxptime:60
a=ssrc:2011742822 cname:/+L6wPj8ErBqYw3L
a=ssrc:2011742822 msid:Mdtr3XiGc3ZYftGDwxeYDfspP9DqQwSRd17N dce80b6d-4fed-4409-af6c-275e470a0d73
a=ssrc:2011742822 mslabel:Mdtr3XiGc3ZYftGDwxeYDfspP9DqQwSRd17N
a=ssrc:2011742822 label:dce80b6d-4fed-4409-af6c-275e470a0d73`


`Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.transaction.ict | z9hG4bK7117302 | Timer D expired for INVITE client transaction z9hG4bK7117302
Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:`

`SIP/2.0 488 Not acceptable here
Via: SIP/2.0/WS cam6bslroe6a.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK4757152;received=172.16.1.209
From: "200" <sip:200@172.16.1.203>;tag=ur4c0oov9u
To: <sip:100@172.16.1.203>;tag=as5f539d65
Call-ID: 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk
CSeq: 7761 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 13.6.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0`



`Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message:`

`ACK sip:100@172.16.1.203 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WS cam6bslroe6a.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK4757152
To: <sip:100@172.16.1.203>;tag=as5f539d65
From: "200" <sip:200@172.16.1.203>;tag=ur4c0oov9u
Call-ID: 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk
Content-Length: 0
CSeq: 7761 ACK`



    `Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.inviteclientcontext | closing INVITE session 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk9t8l09v01c`

    `Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | 4pk6rpr5p1mhfts149uk9t8l09v01c | closing PeerConnection`

    `Mon Dec 14 2015 19:18:51 GMT-0200 (BRST) | sip.transaction.ict | z9hG4bK4757152 | Timer D expired for INVITE client transaction z9hG4bK4757152`
```

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. We are not general server/software tech support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

488 is supposed to means that there is no media compatibility.

There are several reasons for getting a 488: the most common you have no common codecs. Check first that you have opus supported and configured on your asterisk.

With webrtc compatibility, the issue is often related with usage of:

```
UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF
```

instead of

```
RTP/SAVPF
```

ie: the webrtc/ietf standards are not fully defined and still moving.

You can check a possible duplicate question/answer here: [Freeswitch and webRTC: media rejected with 488](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394576/freeswitch-and-webrtc-media-rejected-with-488)

Comment: So did installing Opus help? I'm in the same situation and I've already installed Opus.